# Performance in a 1 million row MySQL-table in a chess game scenario

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, database-performance, database-partitioning

Say I run a game website where the users play chess to each other. I have a MySQL-table that contain all the games with their individual chess moves:

**Games table** (psuedo syntax):

```
gameId INT
player1Id INT
player2Id INT
gameEnded DATETIME NULL
gameNotation TEXT
```

**A couple of rows** can look like:

```
30021, 2001, 3020, '2013-08-01 12:00:00', '1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6'
30022, 3020, 2001, NULL, '1. d4'
```

The gameNotation field can become quite large with 100 moves or more.

*To my question:* My table who is similar to the above contains 1 million rows and counting, which makes it challenging performance-wise.

How would you partition this table (MySQL 6.5)? Or would you perhaps move the gameNotation column to its own table?
I have both ongoing and ended games in the same table, maybe I should move them apart? I'm not sure what would make best sense from a performance perspective.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: one million rows is basically nothing for a database. you need to explain how you're querying the database, because THAT'S where the performance problems come into play. the fastest/most efficient DB in the world can't compensate for badly constructed queries/bad indexing.

Comment: Good comment. I wanted to know what I could do, apart from looking at the queries themselves, to make the table perform faster. But I guess if one million rows is "nothing" then I can ignore indexing and partitioning?

Comment: No, you still need indexing. but partitioning one million rows is a bit of a waste. Consider it once you start reaching the multi-100 millions or billions range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, probably.

```
gameId INT
player1Id INT
player2Id INT
gameEnded DATETIME NULL
gameNotation TEXT
```

I would likely break it out to:

Games:

```
id INT NOT NULL <-PK,AUTOINCREMENT
white_player_id INT NOT NULL
black_player_id INT NOT NULL
gameEnded DATETIME
```

Moves:

```
id INT NOT NULL <-PK,AUTOINCREMENT
game_id INT NOT NULL
move VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL //Change length if necessary
```

Answer (score 2):

This will require proper index, but 1 million rows is not that big.

The key problem is probably with your `TEXT` column, holding multiple values -- and so calling for full-text search and/or linear search. You could change your DB structure to store a single value, probably by moving the *moves* to their own table and using a one to many relationship.

This will have the added benefice to reduce fragmentation since all your records will have the same size (assuming no other variable-size columns).

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean what I stated: "Or would you perhaps move the gameNotation column to its own table?" or split the moves up one-by-one (that would be a many-to-many relationship, right?)?

Comment: A question, if I do not directly search on the column gameNotation, will it's size affect the performance when filtering on the other columns? I do have indexes on the columns I filter on.

Comment: split the moves up one-by-one in their own table. "many-to-many" or "one-to-many", that will depend if you accept duplicate on the target table. Concerning the bare "performances" if you search using index the actual size of a row doesn't matter.